# Check if click was already triggered in jquery

Tags: jquery

I am new to jquery and I will be very happy to have some help to resolve this problem.

The following code will trigger "Click" for a "Div" with class "Toggler". I want to have a if condition to first check if the "click" was already triggered or not and then if click was not triggered then run the following command.

```
                    $(this).find(".toggler").trigger("click");
```

Thanks again for any help :)

**UPDATE:**

since none of the answers worked for me, I am putting the rest of codes here. maybe this can give you a better view on what is my problem and how should I use your code.

This is the main code:

```
(function ( $ ) {

$.fn.SideMenu = function( options ) {

    var oldCode, newCode, side;

    newCode = "";

    var settings = $.extend({
        side:"left",
        autoClose:true
    }, options );

    side = settings.side;
    autoClose = settings.autoClose;

    this.addClass("expandable sidebar");

    if(side=="left"){
        this.addClass("sidebar-left");
    }else if(side=="right"){
        this.addClass("sidebar-right");
    }else{
        this.addClass("sidebar-left");  
    }

    oldCode = this.html();

    newCode += "<div class=\"row\">\n";
    newCode += "    <div class=\"col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg1-12\" data-side=\""+side+"\">\n"+ oldCode+" </div>\n";
    newCode += "</div>";
    newCode += "<div class=\"toggler\">\n";
    newCode += "    <span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right\">&nbsp;</span> <span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left\">&nbsp;</span>\n";
    newCode += "</div>\n";

    this.html(newCode);
//I should put a condition if the slider is open then close it, other wise open it.


    if(autoClose){
        $(this).find(".toggler").trigger("click");
            }


};
```

Comment: if none of the answers worked or you are still facing trouble, let me know so I can help

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, unfortunately it did not work for me. I have updated my question so that you can take a look. Hopefully that help. @AmmarCSE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a flag and set it within the click handler

```
var clicked = false;
$('.toggler').click(function(){
    clicked = true;
    ...
});
...
if(!clicked){
    $(this).find(".toggler").trigger("click");
}
```

**Update**

OP:

> I have updated my question so that you can take a look.

Try snippet

```js
(function($) {
  var clicked = false;
  $('.toggler').click(function() {
    clicked = true;

  });
  $.fn.SideMenu = function(options) {

    var oldCode, newCode, side;

    newCode = "";

    var settings = $.extend({
      side: "left",
      autoClose: true
    }, options);

    side = settings.side;
    autoClose = settings.autoClose;

    this.addClass("expandable sidebar");

    if (side == "left") {
      this.addClass("sidebar-left");
    } else if (side == "right") {
      this.addClass("sidebar-right");
    } else {
      this.addClass("sidebar-left");
    }

    oldCode = this.html();

    newCode += "<div class=\"row\">\n";
    newCode += "    <div class=\"col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg1-12\" data-side=\"" + side + "\">\n" + oldCode + " </div>\n";
    newCode += "</div>";
    newCode += "<div class=\"toggler\">\n";
    newCode += "    <span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right\">&nbsp;</span> <span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left\">&nbsp;</span>\n";
    newCode += "</div>\n";

    this.html(newCode);
    //I should put a condition if the slider is open then close it, other wise open it.


    if (clicked) {
      $(this).find(".toggler").trigger("click");
    }


  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, unfortunately it did not work for me. I have updated my question so that you can take a look. Hopefully that help.

Comment: @Amin, I am confused. You said you want to check if the div was clicked or not. Then why are you using `settings.autoClose`?

Comment: I am using a plugin, I am not sure what all these codes does. 
This plugin make a slider for a div.in other words. It make a div to slide to left or right of a page (just like a menu) and I need this plugin to be activated only if I click on a button and then I can slide it. 
autoClose will close the menu automatically if it is set to true. but basically you can ignore it, it does not matter.

Comment: @Amin, try the code in the snippet in my updated answer

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can use html5 `data-*` attributes to identify whether it was previously clicked or not:

```
<a class='toggler' data-clicked="false">SomeText</a>

$('.toggler').click(function(){
      $(this).data('clicked','true');
});
```

Now before executing below line

```
$(this).find(".toggler").trigger("click");
```

you can check its `data` attribute like

```
if($(this).find(".toggler").data('clicked')!=="true")
   $(this).find(".toggler").trigger("click");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of `data-*` html5 attribute:

```
$(".toggler").click(function(){
    $(this).data('clicked', 'clicked');
    // other operations as is
});
```

then you can update this as:

```
if($(this).find(".toggler").data('clicked') !== 'clicked'){
    $(this).find(".toggler").trigger("click");
}
```

Comment: I think same time we posted.. :)

Comment: @GuruprasadRao and Jai , many thanks to your answers. But I guess I am using your code in a wrong way, I have updated my question. can you tell me how should I use your code?

Answer (score 0):

**[.trigger()](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)** executes all handlers and behaviors attached to the matched elements for the given event type.

To do what you want to do you could deal with a callback function in which you  remove the listener;

try adding something like:

```
    function removeHandler(){
    /*  */
    $(this).find(".toggler").off( "click", "**");
    }

    $(this).find(".toggler").on( "click", removeHandler);
```